# Is there a free or commercial dvd burner sdk for cocoa？

Tags: cocoa, dvd-burning

One of my Windows app used a DVD Burner SDK. I hope to migrate the app to mac.
Is there a free or commercial DVD burner SDK for cocoa？

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provide an API of their very own: the [Disc Recording Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/DiscRecordingFrameworkRef/).

There is even a [Disc Recording UI Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/DiscRecordingUIFrameworkReference/index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/framework/discrecording_ui), too.

Answer (score 0):

There's Apple's [DiscRecording](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DiscRecording) framework.